# When click item on listview, will go to youtube

Tags: listview

I want to do a listview. When i click a listview item, it will bring me to youtube. How can I achieve that? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's simple you can do by yourself, i can give the guide but right your own code.

1. You need attach the JavaScript event to your select tag **on change event**
2. Give the youtube link as value in your list item
3. using jQuery function you can get the value and redirect to youtube

Sample function would be

```
function goToYoutube(ele){
         $url=$(ele).val();
         window.location = $url;
        }
```

In select tag call like this

```
 onChange="goToYoutube(this);"
```